# json string accessing different {} objects with php

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON code in a string that I am trying to parse. I havent used JSON much so this is prolly a simple question.

It is like:

```
$json_code =" 
    {
    "key1":"value",
    "key2":"value"
    },
    {
    "key3":"value",
    "key4":"value"
    }";
```

Im having problems trying to loop through all of different Objects(? - the sets of curly braces) with php.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: That's a syntax error. Are you using nested double quotes that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a JSON literal in PHP like that. Turn it into a string (wrap it in quotes), and then use `json_decode()` to access it in an object like manner.

If you'd prefer to access it like an array, set `json_decode()`'s second argument to `TRUE`.

#### Update

I see you have wrapped it in quotes - you must now escape the inner quotes.

To loop through it, just use `foreach()` on the object or array returned from `json_decode()`.

To visualise the structure once parsed via `json_decode()`, use `var_dump()`.

#### Update

Your problem is, your JSON is not proper - it has 2 objects, but not in array literal syntax. You need to wrap that structure with `[]`.

[See it](http://codepad.org/wp3VOtT9).

Comment: Im sorry I need to better explain. It is in a string, I updated the question.

Comment: If I do that I only get the different keys from the first object in the decoded string.

Comment: @bryan sammon Glad we got there in the end :)