# How to display specific data in JSON in selected id

Tags: php, json

i want to ask you how could i format to give me output where "id" is 142 and stats where text is: totalSessionsWon.

in PHP from the JSON below:

```
{
"summonerId":55595291,
"modifyDate":1477143625000,
"champions":[
    {
        "id":143,
        "stats":{
            "totalSessionsPlayed":1,
            "totalSessionsLost":1,
            "totalSessionsWon":0,
            "totalChampionKills":1,
            "totalDamageDealt":29811,
            "totalDamageTaken":5853,
            "mostChampionKillsPerSession":1,
            "maxNumDeaths":5
        }
    },
    {
        "id":142,
        "stats":{
            "totalSessionsPlayed":1,
            "totalSessionsLost":1,
            "totalSessionsWon":0,
            "totalChampionKills":0,
            "totalDamageDealt":42796,
            "totalDamageTaken":11616,
            "mostChampionKillsPerSession":0,
            "maxNumDeaths":6
        }
    }
```

I am beginner in php and json and i really cant seem to find answer on this question, maybe because i dont know how to ask the question properly.

Comment: Have you tried something? [ask].

Comment: For example you could decode the json data into array and then take your values from it. After that you could encode new json data.

Comment: _Just a note:_ That is not a valid json string

Comment: Fix the JSONString and we might be able to help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json string accessing different {} objects with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011377/json-string-accessing-different-objects-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this was **NOT** valid JSON so I'm guessing you've copied and pasted from whatever source not realising so this has been fixed for the example below.

```
$json = '{
    "summonerId": 55595291,
    "modifyDate": 1477143625000,
    "champions": [{
        "id": 143,
        "stats": {
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
            "totalSessionsLost": 1,
            "totalSessionsWon": 0,
            "totalChampionKills": 1,
            "totalDamageDealt": 29811,
            "totalDamageTaken": 5853,
            "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 1,
            "maxNumDeaths": 5
        }
    }, {
        "id": 142,
        "stats": {
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
            "totalSessionsLost": 1,
            "totalSessionsWon": 0,
            "totalChampionKills": 0,
            "totalDamageDealt": 42796,
            "totalDamageTaken": 11616,
            "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 0,
            "maxNumDeaths": 6
        }
    }]
}';

//Decode JSON and set true for Associative Array for comparison Note yours failed to decode

$array = json_decode($json, true);

 //Use a foreach loop and if statement to pass the data you need into another array

 foreach ($array['champions'] as $value) {

     if ($value['id'] == 142) {

         $statsArray = $value['stats'];

     }

 }


//Show your friends how many sessions you have won
echo $statsArray['totalSessionsWon'];
```

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

**Edit**

Changed `$value['id']` to 142 as it was 143

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i understood the answer and got my problem fixed! :)